# Filter Spark DataFrame by checking if value is in a list, with other criteria

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

As a simplified example, I tried to filter a Spark DataFrame with following code:

```
val xdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("A", 1), ("B", 2), ("C", 3)
)).toDF("name", "cnt")
xdf.filter($"cnt" >1 || $"name" isin ("A","B")).show()
```

Then it errors:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '((cnt > 1) || name)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '((cnt > 1) || name)' (boolean and string).;
```

What's the right way to do it? It seems to me that it stops reading after `name` column. Is it a bug in the parser? I'm using Spark 1.5.1

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to parenthesize individual expressions:

```
xdf.filter(($"cnt" > 1) || ($"name" isin ("A","B"))).show()
```

Comment: can we have a regex in the list so if you want "name" to contains the values ["ABC", "DVA"]  so it should get all rows that have those letters in the name in any position of the full name?

Answer (score 79):

```
val list = List("x","y","t") 
xdf.filter($"column".isin(list: _*))
```

Comment: what does the `:_*` do?

Comment: It's Scala annotation feature.

Comment: what does that mean?

Comment: @WalrustheCat it converts the list into variable number of arguments.

Comment: I believe that `_:  *` is referred to as "splat" (https://alvinalexander.com/bookmarks/scala/scalas-missing-splat-operator)

Comment: Is there a python version of this annotation?

Comment: how about `not in list`?

Comment: @gszecsenyi yes, you can unpack in python using the character *. More here: https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/

Answer (score 0):

We can use **isInCollection** for this as well now (available since version 2.4.0)
[Link to Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@isInCollection(values:Iterable%5B_%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

The code would look like this

```
val filteredList = List("A","B")
xdf.filter(col("name").isInCollection(filteredList)).show()
```