# Is it possible to filter Spark DataFrames to return all rows where a column value is in a list using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I return only the rows of a Spark DataFrame where the values for a column are within a specified list?

Here's my Python pandas way of doing this operation:

```
df_start = df[df['name'].isin(['App Opened', 'App Launched'])].copy()
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33982111/3854235) SO scala implementation and tried several permutations, but couldn't get it to work.

Here's one failed attempt to do it using pyspark:

```
df_start = df_spark.filter(col("name") isin ['App Opened', 'App Launched'])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6660042787423349557.py", line 253, in <module>
    code = compile('\n'.join(final_code), '<stdin>', 'exec', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST, 1)
  File "<stdin>", line 18
    df_start = df_spark.filter(col("name") isin ['App Opened', 'App Launched'])
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Another attempt:

```
df_start = df_spark.filter(col("name").isin(['App Opened', 'App Launched']))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6660042787423349557.py", line 267, in <module>
    raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-6660042787423349557.py", line 260, in <module>
    exec(code)
  File "<stdin>", line 18, in <module>
NameError: name 'col' is not defined
```

Comment: what the result of your attempt?

Comment: thanks. just added the output along with another failed attempt.

Comment: This is because you have not imported `col`.   Try `from spark.sql.functions import col`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As dmdmdmdmdmd pointed out in the comments, the second method didn't work because `col` needed to be imported:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df_start = df_spark.filter(col("name").isin(['App Opened', 'App Launched']))
```

Here's another way of accomplishing the filter:

```
df_start = df_spark.filter(df_spark.name.isin(['App Opened', 'App Launched']))
```